# Inserting into null data into database without submitting the form

Tags: jsp

I wrote the following code to insert data into the database through form but it is automatically getting inserted a null value into the database on loading the page please help me on this.
if possible please provide me an simple example using spring mvc, mysql and jsp.

```
<%@include file="header.jsp" %>
<!-- topbar ends -->
<div class="ch-container">
<div class="row">    
    <!-- left menu starts -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <div class="nav-canvas">
                <div class="nav-sm nav nav-stacked">

                </div>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked main-menu">
                    <li class="nav-header">Main</li>
                    <li><a class="ajax-link" href="deshboard.jsp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span> Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="ajax-link" href="view_emp_list.jsp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i><span> Employee List</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <label id="for-is-ajax" for="is-ajax"><input id="is-ajax" type="checkbox"> Ajax on menu</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/span-->
    <!-- left menu ends -->
    <noscript>
        <div class="alert alert-block col-md-12">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>

            <p>You need to have <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">JavaScript</a>
                enabled to use this site.</p>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
        <!-- content starts -->
        <div>
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blank</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box col-md-12">
                <div class="box-inner">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title="">
                        <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Recruitment</h2>

                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-setting btn-round btn-default"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round btn-default"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-close btn-round btn-default"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>    </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <form method="POST" action="<%
String emp_idno=request.getParameter("emp_idno");
session.setAttribute( "theEmp_Id_No", emp_idno ); 
String emp_cid=request.getParameter("emp_cid");
String emp_fname=request.getParameter("emp_fname");
String emp_mname=request.getParameter("emp_mname");
String emp_lname=request.getParameter("emp_lname");

String sql="insert into tblemployee(fldEmployment_No,fldCitizenship_Id_No,fldFirst_Name,fldMiddle_Name,fldLast_Name) "
        + "values('"+emp_idno+"','"+emp_cid+"','"+emp_fname+"','"+emp_mname+"','"+emp_lname+"')";

try{
    int action=conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    if (action >= 1){          
        String site = new String("view_emp.htm");
        response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        response.setHeader("Location", site);
    }else{
      //  out.println("Not saved");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>" >

                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess4">Employment Id</label>
                                <input name="emp_idno" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess4">Citizenship ID Card No or Passport No</label>
                                <input name="emp_cid" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">* First Name</label>
                                <input name="emp_fname" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning1">Middle Name</label>
                                <input name="emp_mname" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputError1">* Last Name</label>
                                <input name="emp_lname" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label for="control-label">Photograph</label>
                                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                                <p class="help-block">Accepts .jpg, .png, .gif up to 1MB. Recommended dimensions: 200px X 200px</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>    
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
        </div><!--/row-->
        <!-- content ends -->
    </div><!--/#content.col-md-0-->
</div><!--/fluid-row-->
<hr>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>Settings</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Here settings can be configured...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

Comment: Well, you're executing the code inserting data when the form is displayed, so that's not surprising. Stop putting Java code into JSPs. Put it in a servlet. JSPs are view components. Their goal is to generate HTML. Not to handle form submissions or querying a database. The action of a form is not some piece of code to execute. It's a URL to which the form must be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It will make an insertion because the data insertion is happening upon the loading of this jsp page.

Either make a separate jsp that holds your form input components and make its form action as the jsp where  you have provided logic for data insert, or use a servlet for data insertion.

Also consider putting non-null validations on your request parameters

Comment: is there any example so that i can refer to it am new to jsp so please help me

Comment: hi, firstly learn about servlets, and then move to jsp. Understand MVC architecture alongside. Clarity about these concepts is fundamental to J2EE.

You may refer tutorialspoint.com. or Javabrains tutorials by Koushik on youtube. Youtube has many lectures by other authors too.

Hope it helps